# Appium setup error: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: appium

I am a beginner and installed appium to run selenium scripts from eclipse. I have also tried the same kind of code with app path as

/Users/**path to**.app

I launched appium with inspector and then executed the above code . I ended up with the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'vishal.local', ip: '192.168.1.16', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at catietest.CatieTest.setUp(CatieTest.java:34)
    at catietest.CatieTest.main(CatieTest.java:18)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 0.0.0.0:4723 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 18 more
```

I also tried to change the appDir path as "/Users/**path to** /Debug-iphonesimulator"

Even then I got the same error.

Pls provide me a solution

Comment: can you share your base code? it seems like it has problem connecting to your appium port.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added selenium stand alone jar to your project reference jars.

And if you are executing test cases on iOS then make sure you are pointing towards http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub.

If you are executing test cases on Android make sure it is pointing towards https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub.

Before launching appium server make sure you have set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable by hitting the command:

Apples-MacBook-Pro-2:~ apple$ export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1"

then start the appium server and execute your test.